# How do print the console output of the page in Puppeteer as it would appear in the browser?

Tags: javascript, puppeteer

I keep seeing this **WRONG CODE**

```
page.on('console', msg => console.log(msg.text()));
```

That **FAILS**

```
console.log('Hello %s', 'World');
```

produces

```
Hello World     // browser
Hello %s World  // puppeteer
```

Ok, So I thought maybe I could do this

```
page.on('console', msg => console.log(...msg.args()));
```

NOPE: That dumps out some giant `JSHandle` thing.

Ok, So maybe

```
page.on('console', msg => console.log(...msg.args().map(a => a.toString());
```

NOPE: That prints

```
JSHandle: Hello %s JSHandle: World
```

I suppose I can hack it by removing the first 9 characters.

I also tried

```
page.on('console', msg => console.log(...msg.args().map(a => a.jsonValue())));
```

NOPE: That prints

```
Promise { <pending> } Promise { <pending> }
```

Okay how about

```
page.on('console', async(msg) => {
  const args = Promise.all(msg.args().map(a => a.jsonValue()));
  console.log(...args);
});
```

Nope, That prints

```
UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Found non-callable @@iterator
UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 95)
```

Another go

```
page.on('console', async(msg) => {
  const args = Promise.all(msg.args().map(async(a) => {
    return await a.jsonValue();
  }));
  console.log(...args);
});
```

same as before

```
UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Found non-callable @@iterator
UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a
```

I even traced through `msg.text()` but all it does is return a premade string so it's too late to use that.

How do I get the same output as the browser's console.log in puppeteer?

---

PS: as mentioned above, this hack works in puppeteer 1.20.0

```
  page.on('console', (msg) => {
    console.log(...msg.args().map(v => v.toString().substr(9)));
  });
```

but it's clearly a hack and I expect it will break at some point so looking for the correct solution.

Comment: Maybe I just need to file a bug...., given that msg.text is wrong the issue is deeper.

Comment: Anything that passes the browser to node or node to browser get's serialized. So %s and anything else would not probably work.

Comment: If I can get the original arguments then I can call console.log with them. But as seen above my attempt to get the original arguments fails. They are prefixed by `JSHandle:`. I can do `msg.args().map(v => v.toString().substr(9))` to get them but that seems like a hack so I'm ask what's the correct way to do it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
  page.on('console', async e => {
    const args = await Promise.all(e.args().map(a => a.jsonValue()));
    console.log(...args);
  });
```

or

```
  page.on('console', async e => {
    const args = await Promise.all(e.args().map(a => a.jsonValue()));
    console[e.type() === 'warning' ? 'warn' : e.type()](...args);
  });
```

works

Answer (score 1):

You can use `msg.args()`, and the workaround will be like this.

```
page.on('console', async msg => {
  const args = await msg.args()
  args.forEach(async (arg) => {
    const val = await arg.jsonValue()
    // value is serializable
    if (JSON.stringify(val) !== JSON.stringify({})) console.log(val)
    // value is unserializable (or an empty oject)
    else {
      const { type, subtype, description } = arg._remoteObject
      console.log(`type: ${type}, subtype: ${subtype}, description:\n ${description}`)
    }
  })
});
```

Or something like this, to print only the `Error`

```
page.on('console', async msg => {
  // serialize my args the way I want
  const args = await Promise.all(msg.args.map(arg => arg.executionContext().evaluate(arg => {
    // I'm in a page context now. If my arg is an error - get me its message.
    if (arg instanceof Error)
      return arg.message;
    // return arg right away. since we use `executionContext.evaluate`, it'll return JSON value of
    // the argument if possible, or `undefined` if it fails to stringify it.
    return arg;
  }, arg)));
  console.log(...args);
});
```

Comment: Reference: https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/issues/3397

Comment: this is useful info but it doesn't actually answer the question asked.