# Puppeteer and JSHandle@node aria-label howTo?

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer, javascript-objects, flatpickr

I'm using **puppeteer** to try and access the 'aria-label' attribute from the query below but it is returning results of type:

```
    JSHandle@node
```

Which means when I try to **.getAttribute('aria-label')** it is **undefined**.

I am trying to get a list of available dates from the flatpickr calendar.

Can anyone tell me how to do this correctly?

Thanks.

```
(async () => {

    const arias = await page.evaluate(() => {
        const results = document.querySelectorAll('span.flatpickr-day:not(.prevMonthDay):not(.nextMonthDay):is(.flatpickr-disabled)');
        dates = {};
        if (results.length) {
            for ( var i = 0; i < results.length; i++ ) {
                dates.push(results[i].getAttribute('aria-label'));
            }
        }
        return dates;
    });

})
```

Comment: can you confirm that your `dates` is an array in your original code? like this (as an empty object, `{}`) it would throw a TypeError.
other than this, could you share the URL of the page with the flatpickr calendar? for me if I fix the `dates` type above the script works.

Comment: Please share a URL or sample representative markup for the page you're scraping. `dates` should be an array, not an object. Objects have no attribute `push`, which you'd see if you attached a listener to the browser console to check for errors.

Answer (score 1):

When you're running into problems with `evaluate`, the first steps are to [add a listener to browser `console.log`s](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58089425/how-do-print-the-console-output-of-the-page-in-puppeter-as-it-would-appear-in-th) and try the code in the browser yourself.

Let's try running the code in the browser itself, without Puppeteer, so we can see if there are any errors:

```js
const results = document.querySelectorAll("div");
dates = {};

if (results.length) { // unnecessary; if results.length is 0, the loop won't run
  for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
    dates.push(results[i].getAttribute('aria-label'));
  }
}

console.log(dates);
```

```html
<div aria-label="foobar">baz</div>
```

This gives `Uncaught TypeError: dates.push is not a function`. You probably meant `dates` to be an array, not an object:

```js
const results = document.querySelectorAll("div");
dates = [];

for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
  dates.push(results[i].getAttribute('aria-label'));
}

console.log(dates);
```

```html
<div aria-label="foobar">baz</div>
```

Putting that into Puppeteer, we can shorten it to:

```js
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer");

let browser;
(async () => {
  browser = await puppeteer.launch();
  const [page] = await browser.pages();
  await page.setContent('<div aria-label="foobar">baz</div>');

  const arias = await page.evaluate(() => Array.from(
    document.querySelectorAll("div"), 
    e => e.getAttribute("aria-label")
  ));
  
  // or:
  //const arias = await page.$$eval("div", els => 
  //  els.map(e => e.getAttribute("aria-label"))
  //);

  console.log(arias); // => [ 'foobar' ]
})()
  .catch(err => console.error(err))
  .finally(async () => await browser.close())
;
```

I don't have a flatpickr handy so I'm assuming your selector is valid if substituted for `"div"` in the above code, along with the actual site you're scraping.