# Puppeteer gives undefined with $$eval

Tags: javascript, puppeteer

So, I'm trying to scrape web in order to get their elements link as well as id. However, it throws me an undefined as a result. I know that these classes exist because I use `page.evaluate`, which gets specified class without hesitation. Cannot figure out why it is not working. Moreover, it looks like, that the `console.log` is not being printed too

```
  const flats = await page.$$eval(".result-item-v3", (elements) => {
    console.log(elements.length);
    return elements.forEach((element) => {
      return {
        link: element.querySelector(".object-image-link").getAttribute("href"),
        id: element.attributes.id.value,
      };
    });
  });

  console.log(flats);
```

This part works like a charm with exact same class:

```
        const flatsHashId = await newPage.evaluate(() =>
          [...document.querySelectorAll(".result-item-v3")].map(
            (elem) => elem.attributes.id.value
          )
        );
```

Comment: Is the `console.log` printing `null`?

Comment: The console.log inside function do not print anything while console.log outside prints undefined

Comment: You need to use `page.on("console"` to capture the console logs inside the browser. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58089425/how-do-print-the-console-output-of-the-page-in-puppeter-as-it-would-appear-in-th).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just change `forEach` method to `map` method. `forEach` method doesn't return a new transformed array, instead it returns `undefined`.

Like this:

```
const flats = await page.$$eval(".result-item-v3", (elements) => {
  console.log(elements.length);
  return elements.map((element) => {
    return {
      link: element.querySelector(".object-image-link").getAttribute("href"),
      id: element.attributes.id.value,
    };
  });
});

console.log(flats);
```