# Need to be able to print data, created in node.js headless browser

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer, console.log, headless-browser

How to do workaround to be able to print out any data, eg. instant string, variables, etc, created  inside node.js running a headless browser as `console.log('Text')` won't work.
such e.g. is

```
 const pup = require('puppeteer');
 const chrom = await pup.launch({headless:'new'});
 const page = await chrom.newPage();
 await page.goto(aURI);

 await page.evaluate(() => {

              // <= How the code line to achieve this need

});
```

Comment: Just `return` the data that you need from the `evaluate` callback?

Comment: That's only once.
unfortunately the need is multi times; to print out some iteration values in which user tracing a piece of codes

Comment: Are you looking to capture browser logs? "`console.log('Text')` won't work" -- can you clarify what "working" entails? See [How do print the console output of the page in puppeter as it would appear in the browser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58089425/how-do-print-the-console-output-of-the-page-in-puppeter-as-it-would-appear-in-th/60075804#60075804)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [debugging related page](https://pptr.dev/guides/debugging) of official puppeteer documentation.

> Since client code runs in the browser, doing `console.*` in client code will not directly log to Node.js. However, you can **listen** for the `console` event which returns a payload with the logged text.

```js
page.on('console', msg => console.log('PAGE LOG:', msg.text()));

await page.evaluate(() => console.log(`url is ${location.href}`));
```