puppeteer pdf not calling setTimeout in page.evaluate
I'm using node v20.15.0 & have a puppeteer file that goes to a page that has about 200-300 images that are lazy loaded as you scroll down the page.
I created some js that works in the browser if I run it directly there, but when I try to run the same thing in a page.evaluate in puppeteer the setTimeout is being ignored.
Basically it scrolls the page 500 pixels, waits 1.25 seconds to let everything load, then scrolls again using the setTimeout to recursively call scroll_page. For some reason, it just skips over the setTimeout call inside page.evaluate and exits the page.evaluate and continues after that.
var browser;

var puppeteer_options = {
    headless: true, 
    ignoreHTTPSErrors: true, 
    args: ['--no-sandbox', '--disable-setuid-sandbox', '--single-process', '--no-zygote', '--disable-dev-shm-usage', '--shm-size=4gb'], 
    defaultViewport: {width: 1920, height: 1080},
}

browser = await puppeteer.launch(puppeteer_options);

var page = await browser.newPage();

var url = gp_args['url'];

await page.goto(url, {waitUntil: 'networkidle2'});  
await page.setDefaultNavigationTimeout(0)

//enable logging inside page.evaluate
    await page.exposeFunction('logInNodeJs', (value) => console.log(value));

//scroll down the page to get all html
    var retval = await page.evaluate(async () => {
        var retval = {}
        
        var el = document.documentElement

        logInNodeJs('scrollHeight: ' + el.scrollHeight)

        var cur_scroll_top = el.scrollTop
        logInNodeJs('cur_scroll_top start: ' + cur_scroll_top)
        var prev_scroll_top = cur_scroll_top
        logInNodeJs('prev_scroll_top start: ' + prev_scroll_top)

        scroll_page({
            el: el, 
            cur_scroll_top: cur_scroll_top, 
            prev_scroll_top: prev_scroll_top,
            safety: 0,
        })

        function scroll_page(options)
        {
            var el = options.el
            var cur_scroll_top = options.cur_scroll_top
            var prev_scroll_top = options.prev_scroll_top
            var safety = options.safety
            
            el.scrollTop += 500
            
            
            var cur_scroll_top = el.scrollTop
            logInNodeJs('cur_scroll_top: ' + cur_scroll_top + ' previous: ' + prev_scroll_top)
            
            
            if(cur_scroll_top == prev_scroll_top)
            {
                logInNodeJs('end reached!')
                //end_page_flag = true
            }
            else
            {
                var prev_scroll_top = cur_scroll_top
                logInNodeJs('prev_scroll_top: ' + prev_scroll_top)
                
                safety += 1
                if(safety < 20)
                {
                    setTimeout(function(){scroll_page({
                        el: el, 
                        cur_scroll_top: cur_scroll_top, 
                        prev_scroll_top: prev_scroll_top,
                        safety: safety,
                    })}, 1250)
                }
            }
        }
    
        
        return retval
    })

The "safety" is just there for debugging, to try to prevent an infinite loop from occurring, and also to make it run faster while testing. When I run it in the browser the safety is not used, and it works perfectly.
Is there some other way I have to have that recursive call to scroll_page inside page.evaluate?

Your callback-based async code inside of evaluate isn't awaited, so return retval will run immediately with retval being {} and Node will continue on to the next operation without waiting for scrolling. I'd take a step back and learn about promise basics. What are you actually trying to achieve here and what site are you automating? Please share a [mcve]. You can scroll in Node much easier than this. Also, never use infinite timeouts like setDefaultNavigationTimeout(0) and don't disable the browser sandbox unless you absolutely have to (you usually don't).

There are many issues here, but I'll add a simple example to illustrate your main one.
evaluate waits for any promises returned from the callback, but if you don't return a promise from the callback, it won't wait. evaluate has no idea that you triggered a setTimeout--the async callback is not linked up with the main promise chain, so it can't be awaited.
You can link it up with a loop and a promisified timeout:
import puppeteer from "puppeteer"; // ^22.7.1

const html = `<!DOCTYPE html><html><body>
<script>
for (let i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
  document.body.innerHTML += '<h1>hello world</h1>';
}
document.body.innerHTML += '<h1>BOTTOM</h1>';
</script>
</body></html>`;

let browser;
(async () => {
  browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless: false});
  const [page] = await browser.pages();

  // https://stackoverflow.com/a/60075804
  page.on('console', async e => {
    const args = await Promise.all(e.args().map(a => a.jsonValue()));
    console.log(...args);
  });
  await page.setContent(html);
  await page.evaluate(async () => {
    const doc = document.documentElement;

    for (;;) {
      console.log(doc.scrollTop);
      const lastScrollTop = doc.scrollTop;
      doc.scrollTop += 500;

      if (lastScrollTop === doc.scrollTop) {
        break;
      }

      await new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, 1250));
    }
  });

  console.log("done");
  await page.screenshot({path: "proof.png"});
})()
  .catch(err => console.error(err))
  .finally(() => browser?.close());

Taking a step back, though, it's probably better to scroll using Puppeteer--just use the page down key as described in Puppeteer - scroll down until you can't anymore.
Since every page has unique and arbitrary behavior, always share some sort of concrete page under automation to remove ambiguity. If the above approach doesn't do what you expect on your page, share it so I can reproduce and diagnose the problem.

The page is https://magic.wizards.com/en/products/the-lost-caverns-of-ixalan/card-image-gallery. I need it to scroll slowly to give it time to load the images for each lazy load section.

OK, thanks. Did you try adapting my solution to that? How did it go? Are you ultimately trying to do a full-page screenshot, or why do you need those images to load? If page down is too fast, you can use a down arrow press.
